# Send and Receive JSON with Java

Tags: java, json, web-services

I'm trying to send and receive JSON using java GUI, but, i keep getting some errors (like, 500,405,403) with i use the `http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/test-resbeans.html` Them I'm able to use normally, sending and receive JSON with any problems.

For this program that I'm trying to do I also get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://localhost:8080/ClienteWebService/webresources/Cadastro%20Cliente/Cliente/inserir
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1944)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$10.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1939)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I don't know where is the mistake, I tried to make a direct `POST` request using `http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/Cadastro%20Cliente/Cliente/inserir`

and them I receive the JSON, but, if I get the information with a jTextField doesn't run properly or at all.

This is the code:

```
    public static void Inserir () throws Exception {

    ConsumirWs1 http = new ConsumirWs1();
    Gson g = new Gson();
    Cliente u = new Cliente();
    Type ClienteType = new TypeToken<Cliente>() {
    }.getType();
    
    u.setCad_pes_nome(InterfaceConsu.jTextFieldNOME.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_cpf(InterfaceConsu.jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_apelido(InterfaceConsu.jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");

                    java.util.Date utilDate = null;
                    try {
                        utilDate = formatter.parse(jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(InterfaceConsu.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    u.setCad_pes_data(sqlDate);
    
    String json = g.toJson(u, ClienteType);
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/Cadastro%20Cliente/Cliente/inserir?";
    
    http.sendPost(url, json, "POST");
   
}
```

And them the code to send with the Webservice

```
private void sendPost(String url, String urlParameters, String method) throws Exception {

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod(method);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    //String urlParameters = "sn=C02G8416DRJM&cn=&locale=&caller=&num=12345";
    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream())) {
        wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
    }

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    StringBuffer response;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuffer();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}
```

and if I try GET, I receive this error `java.net.ProtocolException: Invalid HTTP method:`

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the String url, here's the code and the format that i needed to make the request in the right link.

```
public void Inserir () throws Exception {
    InterfaceConsu2 IFC2 = new InterfaceConsu2();
    ConsumirWS2 http = new ConsumirWS2();
    Gson g = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy").create();
    Cliente2 u = new Cliente2();
    Type ClienteType = new TypeToken<Cliente2>() {
    }.getType();
    
    
    u.setCad_pes_nome(IFC2.jTextFieldNOME.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_cpf(IFC2.jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText());
    u.setCad_pes_apelido(IFC2.jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter  = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yyyy");

                    java.util.Date utilDate = null;
                    try {
                        utilDate = formatter.parse(IFC2.jFormattedTextFieldDATA.getText());
                    } catch (ParseException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(InterfaceConsu2.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
    u.setCad_pes_data(sqlDate);

    String json = g.toJson(u, ClienteType);
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/CadastroCliente/Cliente/inserir";
    System.out.println("63 consumir");
    System.out.println(json);

        http.sendPost(url, json, "POST");

}
```

I think there's few minor changes in the code, but this works with zero error

also, with is needed to send a parameter to a the webservice, here's another example that I made by myself figuring out how to do it, any other advice is welcome

```
u.setCad_pes_cpf(IFC2.jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText());
    String url = "http://localhost:8080/clienteWebService/webresources/CadastroCliente/Cliente/get/" +u.getCad_pes_cpf();
```

In this one, after this i call a GET method